# How Azure check and run updated code when push to github repository ? Does it affecting on performance?

Tags: azure, web, azure-web-app-service

When i push my updated Angular 2 code to Github Repository. Azure Hosted Web Application with using that git repository immediately serve updated code. Does it check every time for latest changes? If yes then is it affecting on performance?  What is the Azure web app life cycle after code push to git repository ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you link a GitHub repository, Azure App Service registers a Webhook on GitHub.  When you push to GitHub, it triggers a Webhook that then triggers a deployment of the code.  The github repo is pulled (only pulling the changed files, just as if you did a `git pull <branch>`.  It then runs the deployment script (or generates one and then runs it if you haven't supplied one).  The default one does an npm install --production followed by an npm build before restarting the service.

Comment: can we specify npm build for particular environment (prod / dev) ? if yes then how can i do that ?

Comment: Create a deployment script and adjust as appropriate.  I walk through the creation of deployment scripts on my blog: https://shellmonger.com/2015/08/29/continuous-deployment-nodejs-and-microsoft-azure/

Comment: follow article and done successfully , helped me a lot in npm build issue , thank you